# AsyncTask is publishing progress after cancelled

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My situation is a RecyclerView of invoices that can be downloaded. They have an action that starts the download and shows the progress in a circular progress view around the download button itself. I use an AsyncTask to download the particular invoice in PDF format, with a custom listener so I know when is cancelled, executed and progress updated outside the AsyncTask itself (to avoid passing the View and updating it inside the AsyncTask mostly).

This is my AsyncTask so far:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> implements Codes {

    private AsyncTaskProgressListener listener;
    private File file;


    public DownloadTask(AsyncTaskProgressListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = urls[0];
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + url.getFile());
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            LogUtil.log("" + fileLength);
            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), url.getFile()));

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            int lastProgress = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                int progress = 0;
                if (fileLength > 0) {
                    // only if total length is known
                    progress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                }
                //Prevent publishing the same progress various times as it would freeze the progress bar.
                if (progress > lastProgress) {
                    publishProgress(progress);
                    lastProgress = progress;
                }
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtil.log(e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        listener.onProgressUpdated(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        listener.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String s) {
        listener.onCancel();
        file.delete();
        LogUtil.log("CANCELED");
        super.onCancelled(s);
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
    }

}
```

And my listener:

```
tasks[0] = new DownloadTask(new AsyncTaskProgressListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted() {
                                            state = INVOICE_DOWNLOADED;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancel() {
                                            state = INVOICE_NOT_DOWNLOADED;
                                            progressView.resetAnimation();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onProgressUpdated(int progress) {
                                            progressView.setProgress(progress);
                                        }

                                    });
```

This is what's called when I press the cancel button:

```
progressView.setProgress(0);
if (tasks[0] != null) 
    tasks[0].cancel(true);
```

And finally my problem:
I found that when I cancel the download, mostly when it's after 50%, there is one last call to `onProgressUpdated(progress)` AFTER the `progressView.setProgress(0)` so the download is cancelled but the progress bar is stuck at the last progress instead of going to 0 (When you set a new progress, it animates itself in a very cool way).

I tried to workaround this in various ways, like having a boolean on the AsyncTask to know if it's canceled, a method that sets it to true, and a check of it in `onProgressUpdated(progress)` of the AsyncTask before calling the `onProgressUpdated(progress)` of the listener which sets the progress on the view; and I didn't be able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `onProgressUpdated()` and  `progressView.setProgress(0);` both run on UI thread, so you can add a boolean check with them.

1. add a boolean field `boolean noMoreProgressUpdate = false`
2. add `noMoreProgressUpdate = true` after `progressView.setProgress(0);`
3. change

   `public void onProgressUpdated(int progress) {
           progressView.setProgress(progress);
    }`

to

```
 `
    public void onProgressUpdated(int progress) {
        if(!noMoreProgressUpdate) {
            progressView.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
 `
```

Comment: I did it, too. Anyway, checked again. The problem persists: Sometimes, there is a call to publishProgress after I set the progress to 0 when tapped the cancel button.

Comment: i think tasks[0].cancel(true); should come before progressView.setProgress(0);

Comment: ...the codes is copied from AsyncTask source file, not ask you to add this check.

Comment: Changing the order of the methods as you pointed in the comment worked on the UI part. Now I've found that AsyncTask `onCancelled(String)` is called in a while after I tap the cancel button, so you have to wait some seconds before starting it again.

Comment: yes it is possible because onCancelled() may be called after doInBackground() quit. and doInBackground() may blocking in input.read(data) when you tap the cancel button.

Comment: Update: As before, it works 'sometimes'. Calling setProgress(0) after task.cancel(true) also works only when it wants. Maybe shouldn't I use AsyncTask for this?

Comment: ye ye, please call setProgress(0) in onCancelled() callback to fix this.

Comment: keep in mind that, cancel() is not terminate, but notify aysnctask to stop background running. and onCanceled() is asynctask notify you its background running is stopped.

Comment: Now it works perfectly on 5.0 and above, but in 4.4 and before (where the onCancelled() takes a while to be executed) the progress bar blocks during that 'while' before coming to 0. No sure if I should spend more time on fixing it.

Comment: Yep, I have that in mind, that's why I called setProgress(0) outside the callback, to avoid the user thinking 'it's blocked' for a few seconds if cancelling the download.

Comment: add a boolean set before tasks[0].cancel(true) and progressView.setProgress(0), and boolean check before progressView.setProgress(progress)  MUST work for you. because this two all run on UI thread. set true=>cancel()=>set(0) => check(fail)

Comment: That set(0) should be the one I had at the first (outside the onCancel callback) or the inside one?

Comment: Figured out that it should be the outside one. Worked absouletly perfect, thank you very much. Please submit a new answer with this or edit your one and I'll mark as accepted :)

Comment: Just point out that noMoreProgressUpdated must be set to false just right before the `execute(params)` to allow cancelling and starting download again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd  use

```
onPreExecute() {
  //do progress bar here
}
```

and then in `onPostExecute()`

```
onPostExecute(String result) {
   //dismiss progress bar before anything else
}
```